# flutter Android resource linking failed @mipmap/ic_launcher not found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     E:\Programs\Flutter\<My_APP>\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.<My_APP>:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
```

I try to removing icon from android manifest file it works but, I want flutter ic_launcher. Any idea, what is the cause ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to set your icon as a luncher icon of your flutter app?

Comment: Show your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: yes, i want to set luncher icon. I just install flutter and try to run demo app which give me this error

Answer (score 9):

In case you've switched your app icon not only in terms of the image but also the name of it then you also need to change the icon name in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:icon="@mipmap/'Your icon_name'">
```

Answer (score 6):

It happent because your **launcer icon name** and **android_manifest** icon name **different**.

1. first of all goto .....\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi
2. then check the name of your icon is it is ic_launcer
3. then go to android>app>src>AndroidManifest.xml
4. Change
   **android:icon="@mipmap/your_icon_name"**

Comment: thank you its works the best for me, and I think its the easily and explained in detailed, so thanks again

Comment: @MouBiswas It's make me happy dear. Thanks to you also for your remark.

Answer (score 3):

it clearly says icon not found you need to either change name or rename your existing icon as `ic_launcher`

Comment: in my case androidmainfest and mipmap folder name was different that's why this happened when I change the name in androidmainfest then error was removed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I reinstall flutter and now it's works

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you generate app icon from app icon generator website so there is a file name by default such as ic_launcher.png as shown below . So remains it as it is. when you change it name there will be other changes becomes required in VS Code etc.  So leave its by default name ,lets try!!!